# App crashed out of Debugging (iOS)

Tags: ios, debugging, uinavigationcontroller

I am writing an iOS app and have installed it on my iPhone 4, and there is a very weird problem.

When I run it on my device under debugging, it seems to work well when breakpoints are set. However, when I directly use the app without debugging on my device, when I push into a view and pop to its parent view (in a navigationController stack) without doing anything else, the app crashes.  Sometimes it crashes after I do the push-pop action twice, other times only after once.

I've checked the memory management and analyzed it, but have not found any potential memeory leaks yet. Does anyone know what the problem could be? 
Since this problem won't apprear under debugging, I'm not sure how to begin to fix it.

Hoping someone is able to provide me with some experience and clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myselfy,

actually there no doubt that it was because unperfect memory manangement, my app goes well after I take care of all potential leaks.

That is it.